# Access 2016: Short-text validation rules

Tags: validation, ms-access, field, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to make a `full name` field for my Access 2016 database field, and would want to restrict the characters accepted to only be letters or `-`.

What should be the appropriate validation rule to assign this field or would I have to work outside the validation rules to make this work.

Comment: If you're validating full name you;d also need to allow a space and maybe apostrophe too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple validation rule for full name should include only letters, space, hyphen and possibly apostrophe

This one works without apostrophe included

```
Not Like "*[!a-z -]*"
```

It validates that any characters not in that set are not allowed

A couple of great sources for validation examples:

- [Allen Browne's page](http://allenbrowne.com/ValidationRule.html)
- [tekstenuitleg.net](http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/articles/software/access-validation-rule-tutorial/list-of-access-validation-rules)